# gnome-themes-standard tries to overwrite a file from gnome-accessability-themes

Tags: package-management, apt

I was trying to install gnome3 on my ubuntu but because of some reason, apt-get went into an invalid state after the installation (which was incomplete i think). Whenever I try any apt-get operation, I get an error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-themes-standard (>= 2.91) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When I try `sudo apt-get -f install` I get:

```
Unpacking gnome-themes-standard (from .../gnome-themes-standard_3.0.0-2~natty1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-themes-standard_3.0.0-2~natty1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/HighContrastInverse/index.theme', which is also in package gnome-accessibility-themes 3.0.0-0ubuntu1~build2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for gconf2 ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-themes-standard_3.0.0-2~natty1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: try these|

sudo apt-get install -f |

sudo dpkg --configure -a |

sudo apt-get update |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to install two packages that contain the file `/usr/share/themes/HighContrastInverse/index.theme` at the same time. That's not possible. In natty, this file is in [`gnome-themes-standard` 2.91.93-1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/i386/gnome-themes-standard/filelist) and not in [`gnome-accessibility-themes` 2.32.1-0ubuntu1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/all/gnome-accessibility-themes/filelist). You have third-party versions of both these packages, so you should report your problem as a bug to that third party. If the packages come from *different* third parties, then these are two incompatible packages sources, which may or may not be a bug they consider worth fixing. Do make sure that you have their latest version of `gnome-accessibility-themes` first: run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-accessibility-themes
```

The easiest solution to your problem is to wait for the package provider to fix the packages. Or, if nothing depends on `gnome-accessibility-themes`, you could try removing it.

The packaging tools actually offer a way to make two packages cohabit even when they provide a file in common. You can rename one of the packages' version of the file with [`dpkg-divert`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/dpkg-divert.8.html):

```
sudo dpkg-divert --rename --package gnome-accessibility-themes \
                 --divert /usr/share/themes/HighContrastInverse/index.theme.gnome-accessibility-themes \
                /usr/share/themes/HighContrastInverse/index.theme
```

I don't necessarily recommend this: there may be other incompatibilities between the packages that you'll only find out later, and it can get messy if there are a lot of conflicting files. If you try the diversion, `dpkg-divert --remove --rename --package gnome-accessibility-themes /usr/share/themes/HighContrastInverse/index.theme` will cancel its effects.

Comment: I think the package maintainers realized the problem and fixed it. All I did was `apt-get update` and `apt-get -f install` and voila! its fixed :)